# LINQ - order by another collection

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, collections

I have a one collection of elements:

```
public class CompanyVistracksDomain
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int VistracksAccountId { get; set; }
}
```

and another collection of elements:

```
public class VistrackAccountInfoDomain
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }                
}
```

so, I have:

```
List<CompanyVistracksDomain> companies =
    await _companyService.CompanyListHasVistracksIdAsync();
```

and

```
List<VistrackAccountInfoDomain> accList =
    await _vistracksService.GetAllAccountsAsync(companies);
```

They have similar list of elements. **The first sequence contains all the elements that appear in the second sequence.** The first collection is sorted. How to sort second collection like first order?

Comment: What does it mean to sort *like* the first list if the second list might contain elements that do not exist in the first one? How would you reconcile them?

Comment: Add your `DriverVistacksInfoElement` class to the code sample

Comment: "First collection is sorted", I don't see any sort. Why don't you apply the same sorting logic then?

Comment: @Franck, it was mistake, I fixed

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, why you need to know how it sorted? It sorted inside CompanyListHasVistracksIdAsync by specific logic, which can't be applied in GetAllAccountsAsync

Comment: Because the only way you can get two different collections the same order is to apply the same sorting logic. Otherwise, how do you account for different elements? (that exist in one but not the other)

Comment: @ZoranHorvat collections are the same (because second method does requests to external resource by first collection). I just need to have the same order like in the first

Comment: @OlegSh, what you mean by _collections are the same_? Collections have items of different types, how they can be same? Same size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's comment indicates that the second collection is the proper subset of the first collection. In that case, you can simply intersect the first collection with the second one. That would effectively return the elements of the second collection, but in order in which they appear in the first collection:

```
List<CompanyVistracksDomain> companies =
    await _companyService.CompanyListHasVistracksIdAsync();


List<VistrackAccountInfoDomain> accList =
    await _vistracksService.GetAllAccountsAsync(companies);

List<VistrackAccountInfoDomain> sorted = 
    companies.Intersect(accList);
```

If `VistrackAccountInfoDomain` does not derive from `CompanyVistrackDomain`, then you would have to mimic the `Intersect` behavior manually:

```
public IEnumerable<VistrackAccountInfoDomain> Intersect(
    CompanyVistracksDomain first,
    VistrackAccountInfoDomain second)
{
    Set<int> set = new Set<int>();
    Dictionary<int, VistrackAccountInfoDomain> content = 
        new Dictionary<int, VistrackAccountInfoDomain>();

    foreach (TSource element in second)
    {
        set.Add(element);
        content[element.Id] = element;
    }

    foreach (TSource element in first)
        if (set.Remove(element.Id)) 
            yield return content[element.Id];    
}
```

This implementation assumes that there is at least some method to match the elements of the two sequences, for example some `Id` property.

Comment: Does `Intersect` function accept collections of different types?

Comment: @Fabio Just added the implementation when two types are not related but there is an Id field to recognize same objects.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming their ID's are unique for each entry you could try this:

```cs
var indices = companies
    .Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.item.ID, x => x.index);
var result = accList
    .OrderBy(x => indices[x.Id])
    .ToList();
```

edit: optimized a bit

Comment: Wow... This solution has 'O(N^2)' complexity at best, and knowing that OrderBy has deferred execution, the total time complexity will probably be O(N^3 log N). Are you really not aware of that? 100 elements will run for a second. 1000 elements will return about never.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat, I though about it, but seems it's O(N+1)... once executed companies.Select(...) and then orderby...

Answer (score -4):

```
using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<CompanyVistracksDomain> companies = new List<CompanyVistracksDomain>();
IEnumerable<VistrackAccountInfoDomain> accList = new List<VistrackAccountInfoDomain>();

companies = companies.OrderBy(o => o.Name );
accList = accList.OrderBy(o => o.Name );
```